# Show $X^{\star} \in {\rm img}(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that $X^{\star}\in {\rm img}(A^T)$.

$X^{\star}=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$ and $A^TAX^\star=A^Tb$, $AA^T$ is invertable.

I know ${\rm img}(AA^T) = {\rm img}(A)$ So wouldn't $X^\star \in {\rm img}(A)$ too?

Comment: Can you define img(A)? This looks a little strange. if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, it defines a linear operator $A : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ then $AA^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, which contradicts your claim that $A A^T \in img(A)$.

Comment: Let $c\in img(AA^T)$ then $c=AA^Tx=Au \implies c \in img(A)$

Comment: I shouldn't have said $AA^T\in Img(A)$

Comment: Your edit makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and let ${\rm img}(A) = \{Ax | x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$.

Your observation that ${\rm img}(AA^T) = {\rm img}(A)$ allows you to claim that $X^* = A^T y$ for some $y \in {\rm img}(A)$. Do you see now why $X^* \in {\rm img}(A^T)$ instead of ${\rm img}(A)$? It should be clear from the definition of "${\rm img}$".